# Why does my enterprise drive make loud read/write noises only when the computer is idle?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, noise

I purhcased a used enterprise drive off Ebay a while back (HGST Hard Drive HUA723020ALA641 2TB 7200 RPM).

I've got it installed in my Windows 10 PC. It works great, and is pretty much silent while I'm using the computer. I don't actually use the drive for much, other than non-critical backup.

However, if I leave the computer idle for longer than 30 minutes or so, the drive starts to make loud read/write noises, constantly.

Why is it doing this, and how do I turn it off?

Comment: Loud noises from an HDD suggests that it is failing, and you would be advised to transfer all it's data to another drive.

Comment: What do your SMART stats on the drive say? HGST does have better lifespan ratings than most other manufacturers, but that is based on averages, and frankly, I would never buy a used hard disk. generally speaking 1 in 10 hard disks sent through the mail pay for it with their lives.

Comment: @FrankThomas SMART stats all look fine. It doesn't sound like a click of death, it just sounds like the hard drive is reading/writing constantly once the computer is idle for a little while. It's definitely a loud drive by it's nature

Comment: I see Windows 10 in the tags, Windows Defender constantly scans your files. See whether `MsMpEng.exe` is using your drive at those times.

Comment: In your BIOS there are usually settings for which the hard disk is used, quiet, manufacture (usually low noise), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise drives are generally louder than regular desktop drives because they usually are mounted on server racks where there may be a lot of other hard drives reading or writing above or below it. For this reason, enterprise-grade drives are built for durability, which correlates to a loud drive. If you had this drive for a while already and it doesn't regularly sound loud, there is a sign that the drive may be failing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Jonathan Zheng said about the physical build of enterprise drives, Windows is configured to do many things in the background while the PC is idle, including the Indexing Service, Disk Defragmenter, Windows Update and many more. Your antivirus software might also use this idle time to do scans.

If you want to find out exactly what's using the disk, then you may want to look into Windows' built-in performance monitoring tool. [Here's a little guide](https://www.smartertools.com/blog/2016/07/15-configure-perfmon-to-prevent-disk-issues) that may help.